# How would I make a messagebox appear right after the form loads in c#

Tags: c#, settings, messagebox

How do I make a messagebox appear only 1 time on startup instead of every time the application loads.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for using the application!", "Notice!");
    }
```

This seams to load the messagebox before the application starts, is there a fix for that, and make it open only on the first startup of the application.

Comment: How can code in the application possibly run "before the application starts"? If you want the annoying MessageBox to show after the form does, use the Shown event.  If you want it to annoy them once ever, save a setting

Comment: What is nice about the Load event is that it is fired *before* the window becomes visible.  So you can tinker with it, resizing or moving it around without the user noticing.  The Shown event is next.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Form1_Load` will be called before the form even appears. Technically the application already started by the time `Form1_Load` is called, the only thing i can think of that gets called before that is your init method.

```
Public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent;
}
```

If you want to execute code **after** the form has appeared on screen, use the [Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs you can add your the messagebox

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for using the application!", "Notice!");
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

Comment: This would work if you need to show the message once before the form is shown. Use the `Shown` event if you intend on showing that form once (ie: the application closes if that form closes.)